# system function $H(\omega)$ relationship to odd and even components of h[n]

Tags: fourier-transform, z-transform, dtft

What qualities of $h[n]$ are necessary for:

$$
H(e^{j\omega}) = DTFT\{h_{even}[n]\} + j\ DTFT\{h_{odd}[n]\}
$$

**Do all real / causal h[n] have the property that:**

$$
H(e^{j\omega}) = DTFT\{h_{even}[n]\} + j\ DTFT\{h_{odd}[n]\}
$$

where:

$$
h_{even}[n] = \frac{1}{2}(h[n] + h[-n]) 
$$

$$
h_{odd}[n] = \frac{1}{2}(h[n] - h[-n]) 
$$

Answer (score 4):

The DTFT relationships

$$x_{even}[n]=\frac12\left(x[n]+x^*[-n]\right)\Longleftrightarrow\textrm{Re}\left\{X(e^{j\omega})\right\}$$

and

$$x_{odd}[n]=\frac12\left(x[n]-x^*[-n]\right)\Longleftrightarrow j\,\textrm{Im}\left\{X(e^{j\omega})\right\}$$

hold for any sequence $x[n]$ for which the DTFT exists. There is no assumption about $x[n]$ being real-valued or causal (note the complex conjugation $^*$ in the definition of even and odd signals). If $x[n]$ is real-valued you can leave out the conjugation.

Note that the DTFT of the odd part $x_{odd}[n]$ equals $j$ times the imaginary part of the DTFT $X(e^{j\omega})$, so you have

$$X(e^{j\omega})=\textrm{DTFT}\{x_{even}[n]\}+\textrm{DTFT}\{x_{odd}[n]\}$$

(without a $j$ on the right-hand side).

Comment: thanks,  makes sense now.  any suggestion for title?

Comment: @MrCasuality: If your question has been answered you can accept this answer by clicking on the green check mark to its left, thanks.